# Postgres says key already exists although it doesn't

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

My Python application uses Psycopg2 to insert content from a web scraper to a PostgreSQL database. Psycopg2 complains that a certain primary key already exists even though it clearly doesn't.

Error:

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(12345) already exists.
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where id=12345;
-- 0 rows returned
```

What is going on here?

**Edit for background:**

Basically, what the code does is scrape a discussion forum, loops over each page in each discussion thread and inserts some data from each thread into Postgres. The general structure of the code is outlined below. Note that `get` returns a well formatted data structure for each thread.

```
import psycopg2

base_url 'http://someforum.com'
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=mydb user=me')

for i in range(10000):
    thread = get('{}/'{}.format(base_url, i)
    for page in thread:
        sql = 'INSERT INTO my_table (id, foo, bar) VALUES(%s, %s, %s);'
        values = [page['id'], page['foo'], page['bar']]
        cur.execute(sql, values)
    conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Either 1) you've discovered a totally obvious and relatively serious bug in a widely used and heavily tested software product (good job!), or 2) something in your code is causing PostgreSQL to throw a completely reasonable error. Many times in my 40+ years of software development I've thought I've encountered (1). All except once it's turned out to be (2). Without seeing more of your code it's impossible to say exactly what's going on, but you might want to consider that case (1) is pretty unlikely. Perhaps if you post more of your code we could help more. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis: That's a very kind and entertaining way of stating that the question is basically useless without most of the relevant information.

Comment: I never claimed this is a bug in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe Postgres here. Where do you run the `select` statement? Is that the same transaction (and connection) where you ran the `insert` statement?

Comment: Maybe try another key, such as 9876 ;-)

Comment: Your code is insert twice? Without the code this is useless and I'm voting to close

Comment: @trevorDashDash - the most likely issue is that the INSERT is being executed twice with the same value for ID. After the error occurs you won't find multiple rows in `my_table` with `id` = 12345 because the transaction has been rolled back. It may also be that a trigger in the database is executing another INSERT, which could produce the same results. It would help if you'd edit the question and include all the code which is being executed - see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks for the elaboration. I've expanded my original question with some additional background.

Comment: Most certainly, your loop uses the same value twice for `page['id']` and because of the error the whole transaction is rolled back which means nothing was inserted at all.

Comment: After some digging, I discovered that the forum I'm scraping sometimes returns an erroneous number of pages for a given thread. So when the app tries to scrape page number 5 (which does not exist), it is instead redirected to page number 4 and tries to insert the same posts again.

Comment: @BobJarvis Well, there was a hard to trigger bug in 9.3.4 that could cause primary key duplication (!) so it happens. Just rarely, and usually with unusual trigger conditions. I agree that it's too easy to cry "bug" then find out that it was your own code. Been there, done that.

Comment: @trevorDashDash Please post that as as an answer to your own question when the timer permits.

Comment: Good job figuring this out - and I agree with @CraigRinger that you should post this as an answer to your question and accept it. You might also consider using a [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) to generate a primary key ID instead of trusting an external source to supply a unique value.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I discovered that the forum I'm scraping sometimes returns an erroneous number of pages for a given thread. So when the app tries to scrape page number 5 (which does not exist), it is instead redirected to page number 4 and tries to insert the same posts again. Hence the integrity error.